# How Do I Code A Component to Show Different Child Element's Attributes of Base Class

Tags: c#, design-patterns, blazor, abstract-class

I am trying to organize many different request forms into objects.

I am a little too novice to understand how to orient the objects but I kind of understand the behavior I want.

for example

```
public class RequestForm
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public DateTime CreateDate {get;set;}

    public void Submit()
    {
    }
}
public class PTORequestForm : RequestForm
{
    public DateTime StartDate {get;set;}
    public DateTime EndDate {get;set;}

    public void Submit()
    {
        do x
    }
}

public class ChangeDeptRequestForm : RequestForm
{
    public string NewDeptName {get;set;}

    public void Submit()
    {
        do y
    }
}
```

All implements save to the database a record that has a discriminator and a field for the request converted to JSON

Everything seemed fine so far in my developing this and I started to wonder how I display the information.

I'm working in blazor so I have a component that renders the db model and then another component inside it that loads the deserialized request.

```
private RequestForm request {get;set;}
public override task OnInitializeAsync()
{
    request = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<PTORequestForm>(jsonData)
}
```

I'm not able to then do

```
<span>@request.StartDate</span>
```

What patterns should I look at or what am I doing wrong or missing preventing me from displaying the information correctly? Or do I need to make a .razor for every request type instead of something generic enough to handle the different child objects?

Comment: It sounds like you might be interested in using templated components (works/feels similar to generic C# types). Have you seen this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/templated-components?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Is `RequestForm` a simple class or are you trying to use it as a component?  Where are you trying to use `<span>@request.StartDate</span>`?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis RequestForm is currently a simple base class. Any inheriting object is serialized for storing in the db. It is retrieved, and deserialized for viewing. Casting it to the proper object to work with it is what im trying to figure out i guess. Figuring if i will have to write a different component to view different inheriting classes or if there is a better way. 

the span request date is just an example of the cast object being the base class and not having access provisioned for the inheriting class's unique attributes